Is it possible to increase compilation timing attempt?
I wrote a code that, if executed completely, causes the kernel to shut down as well as interrupting the compilation. So, to increase the compilation time I thought of using the following command but without success: even in this case after a certain time the kernel shuts down and not all the required outputs appear. Could someone help me?
Below is the command that (unsuccessfully) I used to increase the compilation time.
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], "Timeout" -> Infinity]

Here is possibile to see the code, whether it helps.

If you include your code—I know it is lengthy—then it can be copied by those who might help you.  From a brief glance, it looks like you are doing a symbolic integration and then finding its numerical value (e.g., N[Integrate[exper,bounds]]),  It may be better to just NIntegrate[…],  If you  limit each input cell to one command, it will be easier for you to determine which part is causing the kernel to hang.

@CraigCarter Okay, I can include my code: I did not do it before because I think the question was closed or donwvoted. Can you confirm it is not annoying?

@CraigCarter Using NIntegrate appears the following error: NIntegrate::izero: Integral and error estimates are 0 on all integration subregions. Try increasing the value of the MinRecursion option. If value of integral may be 0, specify a finite value for the AccuracyGoal option.

It is not annoying, but it is impossible to help you without typing a bunch of code.  Try to construct a MWE that reproduces the problem you have.  For the NIntegrate giving a zero, try plotting the integrand over the domain, perhaps it will become apparent.
